# Custom listview layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android and I can't figure out - how to make `listivew` look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Iblm.png? 
For now I see that `listview` can store only one element per line.

Comment: what you have tried? because design in attached image for ListView row is very simple and easy

Comment: try the followign tutorial, it will surely help you out. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: check this link http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9 which is easier, but you need to build a xml as you required

Comment: Do use @MurtazaHussain Link

Comment: To make a custom list view row you will need a custom list view adapter which has 1 method called getView. You need to override that method and inside it inflate your desired layout (which you previously made and it is in layout folder).

Answer (score 2):

Here is short Custom List tutorial that I prepared. The steps you must follow are;

1. Create a custom line layout
2. Create a custom class that holds the values to be set to the rows
3. Create a custom adapter that will fill the `ListView`
4. Create a `ListView` and in your `Activity`, initialize the adapter and set to the `ListView`.

Basically these steps are used for creating a custom listview. Of course you should have some proper dataset to map to the listview. Here I will obtain tha data from Android's defauls packages in order for anyone to be able to try the code without errors.

**1. Create a custom line layout.**

In this step, you should create a XML layout, for instance, `line.xml` that will form the layout of each row. Create this file under res\layouts directory. For this example, I created a layout that looks like the image you posted. The XML code is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/subimage1"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_holo_light" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subcontent1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/subimage2"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_voice_search_api_holo_light" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subcontent2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/subimage3"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_go_search_api_holo_light" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subcontent3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: Don't forget to give proper ID's because you will use them! This layout looks like;

[image]

Now you have to create a class to fill this layout.

**2.Create a custom class that holds the values to be set to the rows**

Once you have this class, you can create a list or array etc. to hold the values and set to the `ListView`. For example, you have 9 different view elements in this row, so each one will be kept in a field. Use String for `TextView`s and int for `ImageView`s. Create a `CustomItem.java` class or whatsoever and keep it in src\ directory. The class with it's all getter, setter and constructors is as follows;

```
public class CustomItem {

    int image;
    int subImage1, subImage2, subImage3;
    String header;
    String content;
    String subContent1, subContent2, subContent3;

    public CustomItem(int image, int subImage1, int subImage2, int subImage3, String header, String content, String subContent1, String subContent2, String subContent3) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.subImage1 = subImage1;
        this.subImage2 = subImage2;
        this.subImage3 = subImage3;
        this.header = header;
        this.content = content;
        this.subContent1 = subContent1;
        this.subContent2 = subContent2;
        this.subContent3 = subContent3;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getSubImage1() {
        return subImage1;
    }

    public void setSubImage1(int subImage1) {
        this.subImage1 = subImage1;
    }

    public int getSubImage2() {
        return subImage2;
    }

    public void setSubImage2(int subImage2) {
        this.subImage2 = subImage2;
    }

    public int getSubImage3() {
        return subImage3;
    }

    public void setSubImage3(int subImage3) {
        this.subImage3 = subImage3;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getSubContent1() {
        return subContent1;
    }

    public void setSubContent1(String subContent1) {
        this.subContent1 = subContent1;
    }

    public String getSubContent2() {
        return subContent2;
    }

    public void setSubContent2(String subContent2) {
        this.subContent2 = subContent2;
    }

    public String getSubContent3() {
        return subContent3;
    }

    public void setSubContent3(String subContent3) {
        this.subContent3 = subContent3;
    }

}
```

**3. Create a custom adapter that will fill the ListView**

This is tha class that maps your dataset to the `ListView` rows.It takes your `List` (or array) of data, and places them in according places in each row. The `getView()` method does all the trick. You define   all the `View`s here, then set the values by getting them from your list/array. The `position` parameter is the index in your `List` and `ListLiew` too. Here is the code for this example;

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomItem> {

private final Activity context;
private final List<CustomItem> items;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List<CustomItem> items) {

    super(context, R.layout.line, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line, null, true);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    TextView header = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.header);
    TextView content = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.content);
    ImageView subimage1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subimage1);
    TextView subcontent1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subcontent1);
    ImageView subimage2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subimage2);
    TextView subcontent2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subcontent2);
    ImageView subimage3 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subimage3);
    TextView subcontent3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subcontent3);

    image.setImageResource(items.get(position).getImage());
    header.setText(items.get(position).getHeader()+" "+position);
    content.setText(items.get(position).getContent()+" "+position);
    subimage1.setImageResource(items.get(position).getSubImage1());
    subcontent1.setText(items.get(position).getSubContent1()+" "+1);
    subimage2.setImageResource(items.get(position).getSubImage2());
    subcontent2.setText(items.get(position).getSubContent2()+" "+2);
    subimage3.setImageResource(items.get(position).getSubImage3());
    subcontent3.setText(items.get(position).getSubContent3()+" "+3);


    return rowView;
}
```

}

Now everything is ready! We just have to trigger all of these.

**4. Create a `ListView` and in your `Activity`, initialize the adapter and set to the `ListView`.**

In the following activity, I created a `CustomAdapter` and a`List` of `CustomItem` objects, named `items`. Then I filled this `items` list with random texts and items from Android's default packages. It just looks long. However the main code is just two lines, that are;

```
    //Initialize the adapter
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
    //Set the adapter to the listview
    list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

The whole `Activity` code is;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
CustomAdapter customAdapter;
List<CustomItem> items = new ArrayList<CustomItem>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mains);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //Fill the list with random data
    items.add(new CustomItem(R.drawable.abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_input_get, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map, 
            "Header", 
            "Content", 
            "Subcontent", 
            "Subcontent", 
            "Subcontent"));
    items.add(new CustomItem(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_power_off, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_input_add, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_delete, 
            "Header", 
            "Content", 
            "Subcontent", 
            "Subcontent", 
            "Subcontent"));     
    items.add(new CustomItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_menu_month, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_notification_clear_all, 
            "Header", 
            "Content", 
            "Subcontent", 
            "Subcontent", 
            "Subcontent"));

    items.add(new CustomItem(android.R.drawable.alert_light_frame, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_secure, 
            "Header", 
            "Content", 
            "Subcontent", 
            "Subcontent", 
            "Subcontent"));

    //Initialize the adapter
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
    //Set the adapter to the listview
    list.setAdapter(customAdapter);

}
```

}

When I run this code on my emulator, it looks like;

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a demo for this. Once you will define main activity xml and create a row file for this, after that you'll implement the java code which shown to the below. I hope this will work for you.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.assetdbdemo.MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_file.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.assetdbdemo.MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtFname"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Last Name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void setData() {
                try {
                    //Add your array here
                    recordListsAdapter = new RecordListsAdapter(recordsModels, MainActivity.this);
                    lstDetails.setAdapter(recordListsAdapter);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```